# Prevent Array Formula From Returning the Same Answer Twice, Get Next Value

Tags: arrays, excel

So I have a list of employees that I'm working with and potential positions they could fill for our projects. I'm adding members to the team based on whoever is currently working the fewest hours. I've written an array formula that grabs the person at each position that currently has the fewest hours, however, with certain people being qualified for two positions, they often come up under both since they have such few hours. Is there a way using `count()` or another function where I can tell my array formula to make sure the same person isn't already showing up on this team?

My data is set up as follows:

[image]

As you can see, in K2, I have the following array formula that I have dragged down to K9 so that it grabs the employee with the fewest hours that works that position.

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$H$1,MATCH(SMALL(IF($A$2:$H$9=$J2,$A$10:$H$10,""),1)&$J2,$A$10:$H$10&$A2:$H2,0))}
```

The problem is that Kelly shows up for 3 positions and Beth shows up for 2, which is not possible. Is there a way where I can get my array formula to check for duplicates? Do I need to make a helper `count()` section?

Thanks for any and all help, and please, let me know if you need any clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Try this Array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$H$1,MATCH(1,IF($A$10:$H$10=MIN(IF(($A2:$H2=J2)*(COUNTIF($K$1:$K1,$A$1:$H$1)=0),$A$10:$H$10)),1,0),0))
```

Being an Array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image]

This is not perfect, If you put Jennifer's hours back to 35, a tie with Kelly, it will put Kelly as PM and a #N/A in for S2.  Trying to deal with this causes a circular reference.  At that point a little human intervention will need to happen.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this works great! The only issue that I'm seeing is if G10:H10 is changed to 0s, all 3 Marketing positions (M1-M3) come up as Beth, even if she doesn't qualify for M3. It's just finding the quickest match for 0 hours, regardless of if she can do the job. I assume this requires a index double-match, but am struggling to put find the appropriate spot in the formula to make it work.

Comment: Hey @ScottCraner, sorry but I forgot to tag you in my previous comment so I'm not sure you saw my latest question. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: @medavis6 Like I said it is not perfect.  I looked at it for quite a while and can't find a way to deal with the ties without circular references.  It will get you 90% there and then it will need to have human intervention.  You can wait and see if someone else comes by that knows more than I.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'll keep looking into it. I appreciate your help!